# I got an error using jfxrt.jar (JavaFX 2.1 Runtime) How to fix?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I got an error when I try to compile a program with jfxrt.jar (I am using eclipse). The weird part however is that sometimes it happens and sometimes it doesn't. I tried removing jfxrt.jar from my build path, and readding it. For one of the programs it worked and I was able to compile, but for all the other programs I tried it didn't work.

This is the error I got from the Eclipse Console

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000690b022a, pid=7572,     tid=10084
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_40-b43) (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.0-b56 mixed mode windows-amd64     compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x12022a]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of     Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\KING LIN\Desktop\workspace\LoL Build Calc v5\hs_err_pid7572.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Sorry if my formatting is wrong/bad becuase I am new to this site! Any help would be greatly appreciated! I don't think it has to do with my code because it worked for 1 program but didn't for the other...

**Edit:**  I tried exporting to a .jar file, and running with a cmd. The export was successful but when I ran it with cmd I received the same error

**Edit 2:** Here is the hs_err_pid7572.log
http://www.mediafire.com/view/8cvrgnlb3iz51lq/hs_err_pid7372.log

**Edit 3:** Through some testing, I found that importing the jfxrt.jar file doesn't affect the program, but when I try to create a JFXPanel, the program dies and the error above appears

Comment: show hs_err_pid7572.log

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion, I added it. You can find here: http://www.mediafire.com/view/8cvrgnlb3iz51lq/hs_err_pid7372.log

Comment: @user2804925 check out https://forums.oracle.com/message/10056060

Comment: Could you please check the same test case in FX 8 (http://jdk8.java.net/)? I suppose it's a bug in FX, in should have been fixed by now.